# How do you verify developer app install once and forever with Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode8

Once I've upgraded and installed Xcode 8, my developing experience with iOS has gone down the gutter. Most frustrating of all is the need to verify the app *every time* the app is installed from Xcode.

I'm working on simulating data loss so that I can build correct error handling solutions, but when I install the app from Xcode with my device's data connection to off (no wifi, no cellular), Xcode prompts me to verify the app by turning on data connection. This is the case even when I simulate network loss with the network simulator.

I never dealt with this issue in Xcode 7.

Due to this issue, I'm unable to set breakpoints, work step-by-step troubleshooting, and work with the console when I have no data connection.

Is there something that'll verify an app forever, once and for all? I'm not deleting the app from my iPhone 7 each time I install the app. I'm just pressing the play button from Xcode like I always used to.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Register for developer license.

Comment: Apple is the absolute worst. I knew they were making it difficult just to get $99 from me.